# How can I distinguish the same integer object?

Tags: java, list, integer

As known, java cache the Integer from range -128 up to 127. Now, I hav a class container as follows:

```
public class Container<T>{
    private List<T> elements;

    public boolean add(T t){
        //add the element to the container

        //if elements already contains t such that 
        //there is e from elements so e == t
        //the IllegalArgumentException should be thrown
    }
}
```

Now, when I try to create `Container<Integer> container` and then add some into it like that

```
container.add(1);
container.add(2);
container.add(1); //here the IllegalArgumentException is being thrown.
```

I got the exception.
That's not a behavior I wanted. I need to create to different objects for any integer added to the container. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried using expicitly ```new Integer(123)```?

Comment: @bratkartoffel That's not user friendly and counter-intuitive. If you have a method (call it `m(Integer)`)accepting Integer how are you going to pass the 123 value as a parameter? `m(123)` or `m(new Integer(123))`?

Comment: So you're creating essentially a broken `Set`. Why bother?

Comment: @Kayaman What do you mean?

Comment: Well if you want to handle integer as a special case, why not check if the element is an integer, and then create a new `Integer` object with the same value?

Comment: I think you need to decide what kind of container you want.  If you want a set that can contain multiple instances of the same element, then you want a `Multiset`.  (Guava has one, I believe.)  But please don't declare a type that says it only allows one of each element, then try to use trickery to get around it.  Nobody will be able to figure out what you're doing.

Comment: @ajb SEt will not help either. It based on the equals method.

Comment: According to the implementation of your container, this ***is*** the correct behaviour. Another option would be to remove the "throw-on-same" check in you Container. Either way, why don't you stick with Standard Java ```java.util.Set``` which does also not allow duplicates?

Comment: Right, `Set` will not help you, because you don't want a `Set`--you want a `Multiset`.

Comment: @bratkartoffel Because, java.util.set uses the equals method while we're adding some into it. The method is not what I want. I need to use strictly == comparison

Comment: @St.Antario You want distinct elements in your `Container` which is what `Sets` do. But `Set` is well defined so it doesn't throw an exception on adding a duplicate, it simply doesn't add it. Of course it defines the sameness of 2 objects differently (`equals/hashcode` and in `TreeSet`'s case, `compareTo`). Due to the way you've written your class, you have no option but to use `new Integer(1)` when inserting values.

Comment: Of course `Set` uses `equals`, don't be silly. It needs it to determine equality, except in `TreeSet`'s case, where a 0 result of `compareTo` is considered equal (never mind what equals says).

Comment: Basically, make up your mind.  Do you want a container that allows duplicates or not?  If you want a container that doesn't allow duplicates, then you can't have `1` in there twice.  If you want a container that does allow duplicates, then you can't use `==` to exclude elements.  But you seem to want a container that both allows and doesn't allow duplicates.  Don't do that.  Your code will be error-prone and nobody will understand it.

Comment: Incidentally, if you want to check == for equality instead of equals (), you can use IdentityHashMap together with guava's Sets.newSetFromMap.

Comment: @Makoto __Set doesn't use equals__ Are you sure? [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29)

Comment: @yshavit All I want is to disable caching for primitive boxed types. AOr you can propose some other solution?

Comment: @St.Antario:  May have been a bit of a mistype.  I meant to say `==`, but of course, that's a moot point.  I'll go ahead and retract that statement.

Comment: @Makoto All right. Probably the design isn't good at all. Got it, will think of how can I do better.

Comment: I wasn't proposing a solution, which is why I wrote it as a comment, not an answer. :) I was just pointing out that if what you want is an identity-based set, you don't need to write your own.

Comment: Probably not.  If you could clarify your goals a bit, that may lead to a better answer.

Comment: @Makoto I'm trying to validate a tree-like structure for absence of "cyclick reference". So, if have an element, which has some child and the child contains the parent as its child then I need to throw the exception.

Comment: That's an *entirely* different question conceptually than what we've got here.  I'm half-tempted to think that perhaps a new question should be asked, since this one's kind of set in stone.  Describe the tree-like structure you're working with, what you're attempting to do to detect cycles, and why it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: What is the essence of your problem? It seems to me you have come up with a solution for your problem which is a kinda weird one and like @ajb said, it's also error-prone and not very clear what you want to accomplish. Could you instead state your Problem; the Reason why you want to have this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 4):

Explicitly create a new instance of the `Integer` with the `new` operator.

```
container.add(new Integer(1));
container.add(new Integer(2));
container.add(new Integer(1));
```

Comment: That's not a solution. As I wrote in the comment, it's counter-intuitive, therefore will turned out in bugs.

Comment: I'm working on an alternative approach.  In either event, you're going to be instantiating a new `Integer` object to defeat the `IntCache`.

Comment: "I don't like it" doesn't make it a wrong answer. If you want a new object, you have to create a new object. The `new` keyword is the simplest and most robust way to do that.

Comment: @yshavit That's not just "I don't like". If someone except me try to use it, there's 99.9999% probility that they introduce a bug.

Comment: @St.Antario Are you actually intending this for others' use? What's the use case for this `IdentityHashSet` of sorts?

Comment: Javadoc on this function and its usage would go a long way here.  This is a special case of sorts in which certain wrapper classes (and String, potentially) are impacted by caching/interning, and an `==` may produce the exception.  If it's well-documented that one should explicitly pass in a new instance for lower-bound boxed values (and potentially String), this isn't such a bad approach.  Because there are so many different classes that can be subject to some kind of caching, it'd be tough to say that any other approach is valid, or even makes sense; it would get unwieldy fast.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to have special behaviour for `Integer`s you could do a check and manually create a new instance:

```
public boolean add(T t) {
    if (t instanceof Integer) {
        t = new Integer(((Integer)t).intValue());
    }

    // The rest of the code.
}
```

Bear in mind that this is going to get messier if you want to do this for other primitives also.

Comment: And for strings, due to interning of string constants

Comment: @yshavit The question only asked about integers, but yeah; if OP wants to extend this to every type then this is going to get real messy real quick.

Answer (score 2):

You state in the comments, that some developer using this would call this a bug. But as stated by the [Boxing Conversations in the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7):

> If the value p being boxed is an integer literal of type int between -128 and 127 inclusive (§3.10.1), or the boolean literal true or false (§3.10.3), or a character literal between ‘\u0000′ and ‘\u007f’ inclusive (§3.10.4), then let a and b be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. It is always the case that a == b.

There would be a VM-Property to change the size of the IntegerCache (`-Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high`), but you are not allowed to specify any value below 127 or disable it. As seen in the IntegerCache class: `assert IntegerCache.high >= 127;`

So using `new Integer()` instead of auto-boxing is the only proper way on doing this. I would not stick to the solutions pointed out in other comments (as they say too!) with instanceof and creating new objects, as these are neither clean nor the correct way on doing this.

Please take one more look on your architecture. Do you really want to throw an Exception if an element is about the be added twice? Why not using a normal `java.util.Set` and handling it's boolean return value? This would be the most standard Java-way on doing this. Do not reinvent the wheel, stick to existing, well tested and well defined classes.

Comment: *Why not using a normal java.util.Set* : because a `Set` will always consider two `Integer` objects to be equal regardless of whether they point to the same cached value or not. That's not what the OP wants. The OP is aiming for identity not equality.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you allow duplicates in case `T` is a `Number`.

```
public class Container<T>{
    private List<T> elements;

    public boolean add(T t){
        //add the element to the container

        // <<<IF <T> IS NOT NUMBER>>> and if elements already contains t such that 
        //there is e from elements so e == t
        //the IllegalArgumentException should be thrown
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do, if you can change the public API a bit. I would create a subclass:

```
public class IntegerContainer extends Container<Integer> {
    public boolean add(Integer integer) {
        return super.add(new Integer(integer));
    }
}
```

Then I would make the constructor of `Container` protected and add a static factory taking a class:

```
public class Container<T>  {
    protected Container() {}

    public static <T> Container<T> of(Class<T> type) {
        if (type.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class)) {
            return (Container<T>) new IntegerContainer();
        }
        return new Container<T>();
    }

    private List<T> elements = new ArrayList<T>();

    public boolean add(T t){
        for (T e : elements) {
            if (t == e)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return elements.add(t);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Container<Integer> integerContainer = Container.of(Integer.class);
        integerContainer.add(1);
        integerContainer.add(2);
        integerContainer.add(1); // Doesn't throw

        Container<String> stringContainer = Container.of(String.class);
        String same = "hi";
        stringContainer.add(same);
        stringContainer.add(same); // Throws
        return;
    }
}
```

Note that this changes the way users of your API have to create `Container`s; they must call `Container.of` with the type they want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're trying to do but that's not the way to do it.

`Integer` is an immutable class. So any situation where you think it actually useful to have two objects `x` & `y` such that `(x!=y && x.equals(y))` isn't using the class correctly. It's allowed but should never be useful or desired.

This is why it is allowed (but not required) to return the same object from repeated (explicit or implicit) calls to `valueOf(.)`.